# Event extraction in gate

Tags: java, events, gate

I am currently extracting the named entities (i.e. Person, Organization etc ) using JAPE rule grammar.
Similarly can I extract the events from the document? PS : I have created Event jape grammar.
Example event : India Prime Minister Narendra Modi visited USA to meet President Obama.
Can I extract such events like visit and meet ?
Can you please share the code details for event extraction.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  Read that help link and then read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Better questions avoid down votes and yield answers. Not what you wanted to hear maybe but this site has its rules.

Answer (score 0):

Base approach for Event Extraction using GATE described in "GATE-Time: Extraction of Temporal Expressions and Events" paper by Leon Derczynski and others.